# create new instance of user control class in parent project not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have had a problem with this issue for some time now and need help! I have a parent project which is implementing a user control that is defined outside of the parent project. The user control named FullWebBrowser (a webbrowser control) is loaded into my MainPage.xaml which is working correctly, but the problem occurs when I attempt to create a new instance of this user control in other pages in the parent project (that are NavigatedTo from MainPage.xaml).
For quick reference my code is as follows:

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="0">
        <my:FullWebBrowser Name="TheBrowser" InitialUri="http://www.google.com" />
    </Grid>
```

The FullWebBrowser is working properly as well as the MainPage.xaml which controls navigation and whatnot of the FullWebBrowser control now named 'TheBrowser' for usage in MainPage.xaml.cs. 
Now for some reason I am not allowed to call TheBrowser in my other pages that are navigated to from MainPage.xaml, such as SharePage.xaml. Why is this so, and is there a way to access FullWebBrowser named TheBrowser for use in these other pages?

To get around this issue, I have attempted to create a new instance of FullBrowserControl in my SharePage code behind and have named it 'browser'. To note, the purpose of SharePage is to mimic the default Windows Phone Internet Explorer share page menu item option so that I may allow users to share the current webpage url through email, text, or social networks.

SharePage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class SharePage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    //new instance of FullWebBrowser
    FullWebBrowser browser = new FullWebBrowser();        

    public SharePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SocialNetworks_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShareLinkTask shareLinkTask = new ShareLinkTask();

        Uri shareUrl = new Uri(browser.currentUrl());

        shareLinkTask.Title = "Shared Link!";
        shareLinkTask.LinkUri = shareUrl;
        shareLinkTask.Message = "Check out this link!";

        shareLinkTask.Show();
    }

    private void Messaging_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SmsComposeTask smsComposeTask = new SmsComposeTask();

        Uri shareUrl = new Uri(browser.currentUrl());

        smsComposeTask.To = "";
        smsComposeTask.Body = "Check out this link! " + shareUrl;

        smsComposeTask.Show();
    }

    private void Email_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();

        Uri shareUrl = new Uri(browser.currentUrl());

        emailComposeTask.Subject = "Link share from Quest internet browser";
        emailComposeTask.Body = "Check out this link! " + shareUrl;
        emailComposeTask.To = "";
        emailComposeTask.Cc = "";
        emailComposeTask.Bcc = "";

        emailComposeTask.Show();
    }
}
```

It seems that creating a new instance of FullWebBrowser in the SharePage.xaml.cs is not working correctly because when I take the code from each SharePage.xaml.cs click event and place it in MainPage.xaml.cs (and change the FullBrowserName to 'TheBrowser' as it is named in MainPage.xaml instead of 'browser' as named in SharePage.xaml.cs) everything is working properly. Am I not creating the new instance of the usercontrol properly or should I be doing something else that will let me perform the SharePage actions correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you navigate to a separate page the first one is no longer available.

If you have details that you wish to pass between pages, you should do this as part of the navigation process (in the query string). Alternatively you should store them in a globally accessible location such as the App object, a static object or another object that has been instantiated in such a way as to be available to all the necessary pages.

---

Because SharePage has a new instance of browser, the properties set in the instance on the other page will not be accessible. It's like this:

```
var browserA = new WebBrowser { InitialUri = "http://stackoverflow.com/" };
var browserB = new WebBrowser();
```

If you then try and query the `InitialUri` of `browserB` it's not going to be the value from `browserA`.

Based on your scenario:

a) User browses within a WebBrowser on MainPage.
b) User taps a "share" button on MainPage.
c) App navigates to SharePage to select the method of sharing
d) User selects the method of sharing and link is shared.

What you need to do in step `b` is pass the "currentUrl" when making the navigation. Something like:

In `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
NavigtionService.Navigate(new Uri("SharePage.xaml?curUrl="
                                  + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(browser.CurrentlUrl())));
```

Then in `SharePage.xaml.cs`:

```
string urlToShare;

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(....)
{
    NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("curUrl", out urlToShare);
}
```

You can then use `urlToShare` in your `SocialNetworks_Click` and `SocialNetworks_Click` methods.

Yes, there are other ways of doing it, but this is probably the simplest, based on my understanding of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Matt_Lacey so you are saying that even creating a new instance of this outside user control in my SharePage.xaml.cs will not allow me to access the same functionality in my SharePage.xaml.cs code behind as when I added the outside user control to my MainPage.xaml xaml code? That is confusing to me. If so, how and where should I instantiate this outside user control to be available in all pages (even if i have it defined in my MainPage.xaml to render the webbrowser on that page)? Thanks for your response by the way!

Comment: @Matthew If you create a new instance of it in the "SharePage" then it won't be the same control so trying to access it's properties will be pointless. Let me update and expand my answer.

Comment: @Matt_Lacey that implementation works great! I really do appreciate you explaining in those terms regarding the creation of a new instance of the webbrowser control not passing the url and the implementation of querystring to pass the currentUrl() method. Thanks!

Comment: @Matthew accepts and upvotes are the way we say thank you round here ;)